# Name for Jewish black suit and hat costume?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for the [black suit and brimmed hat (Google Images)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=jewish+men+orthodox&tbm=isch) worn by some Jewish men? It is not mentioned in [Jewish religious clothing (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jewish_religious_clothing).

Comment: The clothing is often just called *Jewish clothing*, or is referred to as *Hasidic* or *Yeshivish* clothing. While there are specific names for some of the more traditional garb, the terms are either Yiddish or Hebrew, not English. There is some discussion [here](http://www.orthodox-jews.com/orthodox-jewish-clothing.html#axzz4HnO7LGvD), including some of the terms. Also, different sects favor different traditional garb.

Comment: ***Jewish headgear*** - https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:Jewish_headgear

Comment: Hasidic apparel?

Comment: In  of the pictures there is  the ***Shtreimel*** https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shtreimel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long, black coats that are different from typical Western sport- or suit-jackets are typically worn by various kinds of [Hasidic Jewish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasidic_Judaism) men. They have different styles and go by different names in different sects. Some variants are:

- [*Bekishe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bekishe)
- [*Rekel*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rekel)
- [Frock coat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frock_coat)

Wide-brimmed black hats of various styles are typically worn by a broader cross-section of Orthodox Jewish men, including most [Haredis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haredi_Judaism), whether Hasidic or not. I've only ever heard of these referred to, generically, as "black hats." I have also heard of particular styles called by their conventional English names, including "[fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora)" and "[homberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homburg_(hat)#Jewish_Rabbinical_Use)." If there's a particular Yiddish or Hebrew expression for these hats, I'm not aware of it.

Many of the men who wear black hats also wear dark-colored typical Western [suits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit_(clothing)).